# Tomcat log policy

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

I'm parsing gigantic Tomcat log files and I was wondering: when you stop, redeploy and then restart a Webapp, do the logs get automatically appended to the last *debug.log*.

More specifically: can you see in a unique *debug.log* file logs coming from two different deployments of a same *.war*?

So, for example, can you have logs from up to 11am from, say, version 1.0 of, say, *example.war* and then logs from 1pm coming from, say, version 1.1 of *example.war* in the same *debug.log*?  Is this depending on the logger used and the way it is configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat will debug every error in the same log file, it doesnt matter if there is two different war files. Try using log4j (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/logging.html) it allows you to separate everything into different log files.